# Which bombs will I drop?

Tags: war-thunder

In war thunder several aircraft can be loaded with a mix of bombs of a different weight, for example a plane might be carrying 2 250kg bombs and 2 500kg bombs.

When you drop bombs in what order will they be dropped? Is it random, or is there always some order to them?

Comment: I know it's not random, but I'm not sure if it's heavier bombs first or lighter. You could just drop them at low alt and see them. its pretty easy to tell 250 and 500 apart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order in which the bombs drop depends on the plane. Some planes drop the bombs fitted on the wings first, others drop them from the bay.

Bombs on the wings tend to be the smaller weight bombs. If a bomber is dropping ordinance from the bay usually the big ones go first.

So it all really depends on the type of plane you're flying, the only rule is that the same plane with the same load-out will always drop the bombs in the same order.